# Set Camera to Front or Back ng-file-upload

Tags: ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload in an AngularJS app to take a picture of the user.  Is there a way to set the camera to use the front camera?  The button to take a picture looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
    ng-model="mobilePhoto"
    ngf-select="selectPhoto($event, $file)"
    ngf-capture="'camera'"
    accept="image/*">Launch Camera
</button>
```

And is working fine, I'd like to make sure it uses the camera on the front of the phone.

I found this page: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-gettingstarted

which makes it look like it is possible to choose which camera to use with `MediaStreamTrack.getSources()` from my web app.  Can this be done with ng-file-upload?  If not, is it possible to write a function which will integrate with ng-file-upload to allow me to set which camera to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That html5rock link doesn't seem to work on my iPhone 6, Chrome 47

Comment: @danial I changed the link text to the actual URL, hopefully at worst you can copy and paste unless it's the actual website that doesn't work.

Comment: Oh the link works but the demo page does not show any options, saying that my browser does not supports it and I should use Chrome even though I open the link with Chrome.

Comment: If you could find a working example of using it in chrome I could go for adding it to the plugin.

Comment: Oh I see.  It works on my nexus 6, but not as advertised.  The implication is that you can keep switching cameras via the drop down, but I find that I can select which camera from the drop down initially, but then after I hit Allow in the security popup, that it will use the camera I've selected but I can't keep switching between cameras.  However, being able to switch cameras is less important (for me anyway) than being able to set the camera initially - which this does.  But if it only works on one phone that's no good.  I'll keep looking and see if I can find something else. Thanks!